# Environment variables in build and run time with webpack 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

in my code I have process.env that I need to define in the run time, not the build time. Is there any way to achieve it? I would like to build the bundle for a specific reason and use the envs to determine the environment, but the app is ran on a different machine than it's being built, so I need to pass some envs in the build time and run time.

What would be the webpack way to differentiate the envs - these that are available in the build time and these available in the run time?

```
"build": "webpack --mode=production",
"build:qa": "ENV=qa webpack --mode=production",
"build:prod": "ENV=prod webpack --mode=production",
```

Comment: Is it CRA? Or ejected cra? Please show your webpack config

Comment: You can't change environment variables in run time. They are only one time of envs and it's build-time. You should just pass the final env variables when building or build on the final machine

Answer (score 0):

Webpack’s DefinePlugin allows you to create global variables which can be configured at compile time. This enables you to change the behavior of your code in different environments ( e.g. production and dev ).

This is how you can use DefinePlugin:

````
new webpack.DefinePlugin(
 Object.keys(process.env)
 .filter((key) => key.startsWith(‘WEBPACK_DEMO_’))
 .reduce(
 (result, key) => ({
 …result,
 [`process.env.${key}`]: JSON.stringify(process.env[key])
 }),
 {}));
```
````

This goes through the keys you have in your local ‘process.env’ and filters them to keys that only start with the string ‘WEBPACK_DEMO_’. It then reduces through these keys and builds an object from these with ‘process.env’ as a prefix. This way of setting environment variables at build time to use at runtime gives you the most control but also requires a larger amount of code.

For more about other approaches, you can visit [here](https://medium.com/@tasha.pudin/how-to-use-environment-variables-with-webpack-3e7fbf1181f6)